# Call endpoint within sveltekit beforeNavigate function and cancel navigation based on response

Tags: routes, svelte, sveltekit

I want to call a route verification endpoint inside sveltekit's `beforeNavigate` method and prevent moving to the new route based on that endpoint response status.

I'm unable to cancel routing using `cancel()` after make an endpoint call. It will not work if used after the call, right where I get the response.

What am I missing here?

This is what i have:

```js
// __layout.svelte
beforeNavigate(async ({ to, from, cancel }) => {
    // > cancel() will work if here

    const url = to || from;

    const path = url ? url.pathname.slice(1, url.pathname.length) : null;

    // cancel() will work if here
    
    try {

       // > cancel() will work if here

       const response = await fetch(`/api/check?path=${path}`, {
          method: 'GET',
       });

       // > cancel() will not work here

       if ([401, 403].includes(response?.status)) {
          displayNotification('Not authorized');
          cancel(); // not working
       }
    } catch (error) {
       displayNotification('Something went wrong!');
       cancel(); // not working
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beforeNavigate` does not support asynchronous functions like this. A workaround is to always `cancel` first, then trigger a new navigation using [`goto`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto). Note that this is not intended and will mess up the browser history when the function is called on a back navigation.

See also [this comment](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4421#issuecomment-1129879937) by Rich Harris.

As `goto` will cause `beforeNavigate` to be invoked again, you might need to use some local state or a URL parameter to make sure you do not end up in an infinite loop. E.g.

```js
beforeNavigate(async ({ to, cancel }) => {
    if (to.searchParams.has('go')) {
        to.searchParams.delete('go');
        return;
    }

    cancel();
    await delay(1000); // Simulate async check

    to.searchParams.append('go', '');
    goto(to.toString());
});
```

Comment: That workaround solve it! Do you think it might be a better approach to move the `api/check` endpoint call to the handle hook instead? As you point out.. this is a workaround

Comment: @JulianoSilva Possibly, if the hook has enough information to serve all cases. I have not used `handle` before so I cannot say for certain.

Comment: `goto` has a `replaceState` option and beforeNavigate arg has a type property where you can check for the `popstate` type which means back button was pressed. You can use this to not mess up the browser history.